# Scrape hyperlinks from an html page

Tags: html, r

I am trying to extract the latitudes and longitudes for the places listed on the right side of [this](http://www.indiamapia.com/Bankura.html) page. I want to create a table like the following:

```
Place  Latitude Longitude
Agarda 23.12604 87.19869 
Ahanda 23.13099 87.18501 
.....
.....
West-Sanabandh 23.24876 86.99941
```

Is it possible to do this in R without calling up the individual hyperlinks for "Agarda:, "Ahanda"... etc. one at a time?

Comment: I don't have the time to give you a full working example, but have a look at how I scraped a genealogy archive: https://github.com/romunov/GEDCOM-archives/blob/master/gedcom-archive.R

Answer (score 3):

The data appears on different pages. You can't get that data without requesting each page.

If R supports threads then you can call them up in parallel rather than one at a time.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks for the confirmation, Quentin.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use RCurl to scrape each page in some type of loop or sapply. If you combine it with some regex and/or readHTMLTable (to identify the hyperlinks) then it's a relatively straightforward function.

Within RCurl, it's possible to create a multicurl which will do this in parallel, although given the number of queries involved, it might be just as easy to serialise it and put a small system sleep between queries.